# How to get an integer value to a complex dictionary

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Here the value of abc is an integer and total is a dictionary which contains another dictionaries.But when I run this line,

```
    total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = abc
```

This error is shown : `"KeyError: None"`
Please Help

What I want from this statement is to get the abc's value to the key 'total_transport_allowance'

```py
def print_excel_report(self,cr,uid,ids,data,context=None):
    result = self._get_lines(cr,uid,ids,data)
    filename= 'PayrollRegister.xls'
    workbook= xlwt.Workbook(encoding="UTF-8")
    sheet= workbook.add_sheet('Payroll Register',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    style = xlwt.easyxf('font:height 400, bold True, name Arial; align: horiz center, vert center;borders: top medium,right medium,bottom medium,left medium')
    a = range(1,10)
    row = 1
    col =0
    header = ['Division','Basic','Transport Allowance']
    style2 = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1')
    total = {}

    for index,data in enumerate(result):
        div = data.get('Division',False)
        abc = data.get('transport_allowance',False) or 0

        if div:
            if div in total:
                total[div]['total_basic'] = total[div]['total_basic'] +  data.get('basic',0)
                total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] +  abc
            else:
                total[div] = {}
                total[div]['total_basic'] =  data.get('basic',0)
                total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = abc

        else:
            if 'Undefined' in total:
                total['Undefined']['total_basic'] = total['Undefined']['total_basic'] +  data.get('basic',0)
                total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] + abc

            else:
                total['Undefined'] = {}
                total['Undefined']['total_basic'] =  data.get('basic',0)
                total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = abc
        .......
        .....
```

Comment: Please show us more code around the problem. Especially what `div` and `abc` are. Ideally a minimal example that is runnable for itself and still shows your problem.

Comment: abc has values from 0.
div is an internal dictionary.

Comment: This does not help with solving your problem. Please edit your question and paste a minimal, complete, verifiable example so we can help you. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: @mrCarnivore 
`total[div]['total_gross'] =  data.get('gross',0)`
This code is runnable.
Problem arises when I try to add none values

Comment: From reading your error, `div` is None. Post a [mcve]

Comment: @vbt: last try to help you: _edit your question_! And provide a _runnable and complete example_!

Comment: please add the rest of your code

Comment: @ddor254 : Full code is added now

Comment: This is neither your "full code", nor a [mcve]. What is "result"?

Comment: @khelwood Full code is very long so I just added the needed part

Comment: really....try a minimum example reproducing your error

Comment: **Actually read this**: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to put in some effort to fix this question.

Comment: @khelwood : how to replace none with another value ?

Comment: @khelwood Sorry khelwood I will make the code more understandable.

Comment: This is not minimal, and it can't be run because the indentation is screwed up. Also, inserting masses of redundant blank lines is not making your code easier to read.

Comment: when you ask question related to `openerp` put only those tag
this why you get a lot of down votes. and post a little code not the whole code

Comment: @Tchi-Odoo Ok Tchi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `div` is `None`:

```py
 if div:
    ....
    ....
 else:
    ...
    ...
    # div here is None or False ..
    # you cannot use it as key!!
    total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = abc
```

You need to define the key here first. so where
you want to put the abc when div is None.

**EDIT**

I don't know what the value of div should when it's not in `data.get('Division',False)`:

```py
    div = data.get('Division', False)
    ...
    ...
    if div:
       .....
    else:
        # assing a value to div
        div = 'NEW_VALUE'
        # add dictionary there
        total[div] = {}
        if 'Undefined' in total:
            ....
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: How to define a key first ?
So much confusing due to complex dictionary

Comment: check my edit hope this give an idea of what you should do

Comment: Tchi , this part is working fine.
In some part,
`total_transport_allowance` 's value is none and that is causing `None Error`
Anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To try and rescue something from all the downvotes:

You have an if statment checking the truthy of `div`. In the falsey case you then use div to access total.

ie you have:

```
if div:
    # stuff
else:
    # stuff
    total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = abc
```

As total doesn't have the key div, this doesn't work.

you need something like `total[div] = {}`

Comment: Won't it create a  new field as total-->div-->total_transport_allowance

Comment: Because in other cases,it works fine.
It shows error only in the "total_transport_allowance" 's case because here some values are blank and in other cases,no values are blank.

Comment: `total[div] = {}` is present

Comment: Probably wasting my time explaining at this point. total[div] = 0 is in the other branch of the if statement, when div has a different value.

Answer (score 1):

```
total[div]['total_transport_allowance'] = {}
```

This worked.. 
I have done like this in

```
total['Undefined']['total_transport_allowance'] = {}
```

also..
Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

KeyError is None means not defined dictionary. div is a dictionary should be defined.